# MySQL where "current Id" of the query

Tags: mysql, select, mariadb

Hello I am trying for a moment to get the time difference between each activity and activity 1 but I only succeed by filling in a particular activity and therefore obtain each line with this difference.

```sql
select 
  name, 
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, 
                (select ts 
                         from feed 
                         where TeamId=1 and ActivityId=1), 
                 (select ts 
                    from feed 
                    where TeamId=1 and ActivityId=4)) 
from activity 
inner join feed on feed.ActivityId = activity.id 
where TeamId=1 order by FeedId DESC;
```

```
+------+-----------------------------------------------------+ 
| act4 |                                                1105 | 
| act3 |                                                1105 | 
| act3 |                                                1105 | 
| act2 |                                                1105 | 
| act1 |                                                1105 |
+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

I want my final results to look like this:

```
+------+-----------------------------------------------------+ 
| name |                                       TIMESTAMPDIFF |
+------+-----------------------------------------------------+ 
| act4 |                                                1105 | 
| act3 |                                                11   | 
| act3 |                                                11   | 
| act2 |                                                1    | 
| act1 |                                                0    | 
+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

I would therefore like to obtain on each line the time difference between the activity selected by the select and activity 1. does anyone have an idea how to go about it?

This is feed :

```
+--------+---------------------+------------+--------+
| FeedId | ts                  | ActivityId | TeamId |
+--------+---------------------+------------+--------+
|      1 | 2022-12-20 16:21:30 |          1 |      1 |
|      2 | 2022-12-20 16:21:30 |          1 |      2 |
|      3 | 2022-12-20 16:21:30 |          1 |      3 |
|      4 | 2022-12-20 16:21:30 |          2 |      1 |
|      5 | 2022-12-20 16:21:30 |          3 |      1 |
|      6 | 2022-12-20 16:21:30 |          2 |      2 |
|      7 | 2022-12-20 16:38:54 |          3 |      1 |
|      8 | 2022-12-20 16:39:55 |          4 |      1 |
+--------+---------------------+------------+--------+
```

and this is activity :

```
+----+--------------+------+-------+
| id | localisation | name | point |
+----+--------------+------+-------+
|  1 | Madras       | act1 |  -650 |
|  2 | Valparaiso   | act2 |   450 |
|  3 | Amphi        | act3 |    45 |
|  4 | Amphix       | act4 |  4589 |
+----+--------------+------+-------+
```

Comment: Can you update your post with sample input table?

Comment: what do you mean by sample input table ?

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must have made an error copying the source.... but this looks pretty close:

```sql
select
   name,
   f1.ts time1,
   f4.ts time4,
   TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,f1.ts,f4.ts)
from activity a
left join feed f1 on f1.ActivityId = 1 and f1.TeamId=1
left join feed f4 on f4.ActivityId = a.id and f4.TeamId=1
order by name  desc;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/8l37JqS8)

output of this is:

| name | time1 | time4 | TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,f1.ts,f4.ts) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| act4 | 2022-12-20 16:21:30 | 2022-12-20 16:39:55 | 1105 |
| act3 | 2022-12-20 16:21:30 | 2022-12-20 16:21:30 | 0 |
| act3 | 2022-12-20 16:21:30 | 2022-12-20 16:38:54 | 1044 |
| act2 | 2022-12-20 16:21:30 | 2022-12-20 16:21:30 | 0 |
| act1 | 2022-12-20 16:21:30 | 2022-12-20 16:21:30 | 0 |

Comment: P.S. Sorry for the `FIELD6` in the dbfiddle, but that is because of the **missing** "Can you update your post with sample input table?"  